# Using JQ for statistical aggregation of key values in a large data set

Tags: jq

I have a complex use case that I can currently mostly solve with JQ, but am wondering if JQ is no longer the right tool for the job, or if there is a way I can generalize my filter. The use case is to create a statistical aggregate of sorted key value counts in large data set of newline delimited JSON. The issue I am running into relates to the number of keys in my data set becoming too large of a filter for jq to actually compile.

Below is a sample input, note that it includes arrays.

**Input: (input.json)**

```
{
  "content": {
    "user": {
      "name": "Bill",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "shovel",
          "details": {
            "heavy": false
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "hammer",
        }
      ],
      "details": {
        "age": 60
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "content": {
    "user": {
      "name": "Bill",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "shovel",
          "details": {
            "heavy": false
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "hammer",
        }
      ],
      "details": {
        "age": 21
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "content": {
    "user": {
      "name": "Alice",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "hammer",
          "details": {
            "heavy": true
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "shovel",
        }
      ],
      "details": {
        "age": 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My desired output is below, essentially I get a listing of all keys in the structure, including array indices, with a sorted count by key value.

**Output:**

```
{
  "stats": {
    "user.name": {
      "Bill": 2,
      "Alice": 1
    },
    "user.items.0.name": {
      "shovel": 2,
      "hammer": 1
    },
    "user.items.1.name": {
      "hammer": 2,
      "shovel": 1
    },
    "user.items.0.details.heavy": {
      "true": 1,
      "": 2,
    },
    "user.items.1.details.heavy": {
      "true": 1,
      "": 2
    },
    "user.details.age": {
      "30": 1,
      "62": 1,
      "21": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Current Problematic Solution:**

Currently I initially get a list of all keys in the json input `[content.user.name, content.user.items.1.name, etc.]` and use that to construct a jq filter.

For context, here is the jq filter I use to get **keys**
`select(objects)|=[.] | map( .content | paths(scalars)) | map(join(".")) | unique`

The current aggregation filter looks like this (for just a single content.user.name aggregate calculation):

```
cat input.json | jq -c -s '{"stats": {"user.name": (map(.content."user"?."name"?) 
| del(..|nulls) | map(. | tostring) 
| reduce .[] as $i ( {}; setpath([$i]; getpath([$i]) + 1)) 
| to_entries | sort_by(.value) | reverse | from_entries)}}'
```

So to add more aggregate calculations, I use this template:

```
(newlines added for legibility)

"{KEY}": (map(.content.{KEY})
| del(..|nulls) | map(. | tostring)
| reduce .[] as $i ( {}; setpath([$i]; getpath([$i]) + 1))
| to_entries | sort_by(.value) | reverse | from_entries)
```

Filter including content.user.details..age

```
cat input.json | jq -c -s '{"stats": {"user.name": (map(.content."user"?."name"?) 
| del(..|nulls) | map(. | tostring) 
| reduce .[] as $i ( {}; setpath([$i]; getpath([$i]) + 1)) 
| to_entries | sort_by(.value) | reverse | from_entries),
"user.details.age": (map(.content."user"?."details"?."age"?) 
| del(..|nulls) | map(. | tostring) 
| reduce .[] as $i ( {}; setpath([$i]; getpath([$i]) + 1)) 
| to_entries | sort_by(.value) | reverse | from_entries)}}'
```

So the size of my filter grows linearly with the number of keys in the data set. Which means for large data sets, my filter actually grows too large for jq to compile. I'm not sure if I have been staring at this too long, but I am not sure if this is a problem best solved by jq. If I reduce the size of my key aggregation template, I am still capped by the max filter size at some number of keys, and I can't seem to find a way to map the original keys in order to reuse the template while iterating through keys. This would mean recalculating keys for each newline JSON which isn't optimal but not sure around that either

**TLDR;**

I want to aggregate key values by key from some newline delimited json.

Some pseudocode of what would be the ideal solution is below, but I cannot get it to work.

```
get keys:
select(objects)|=[.] | map( .content | paths(scalars)) | map(join(".")) | unique

iterate through all keys and run:
"{KEY}": (map(.content.{KEY})
| del(..|nulls) | map(. | tostring)
| reduce .[] as $i ( {}; setpath([$i]; getpath([$i]) + 1))
| to_entries | sort_by(.value) | reverse | from_entries)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `--stream` option to read in the big input in smaller pieces

```sh
jq --stream -n '
  {stats: (reduce (1 | truncate_stream(inputs)) as $i ({};
    if ($i | has(1)) then ."\($i[0] | join("."))"."\($i[1])" += 1 else . end
  ))}
' input.json
```

```json
{
  "stats": {
    "user.name": {
      "Bill": 2,
      "Alice": 1
    },
    "user.items.0.name": {
      "shovel": 2,
      "hammer": 1
    },
    "user.items.0.details.heavy": {
      "false": 2,
      "true": 1
    },
    "user.items.1.name": {
      "hammer": 2,
      "shovel": 1
    },
    "user.details.age": {
      "60": 1,
      "21": 1,
      "30": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like I need to read up on the stream option some more before I can wrap my head around this completely but after trying on several inputs this works really well. Much appreciated @pmf

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is a JSON stream, you should be able to obtain a straightforward but performant solution using `inputs` and the -n command-line option.  Based on my understanding of the problem, here's what I get:

```
def summary(stream):
   reduce stream as [$p, $v] ({};
      ($p|join(".")) as $q
      | if .[$q] then .[$q][$v|tostring] += 1
      else .[$q] = {($v|tostring): 1}
      end);

{stats: summary(inputs.content
        | paths(scalars) as $p
        | [$p, getpath($p)]) }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. This one is quite clear to me. However I ran into performance issues with data structures with many keys, so I created a comparison node.js script that reads each line, parses and flattens it, then updates a counter in a global stats data structure. It seems to be at least an order of magnitude faster, but from my understanding it's doing the same thing as the jq filter above. I don't see where some expensive combinatorial operation could be creeping in but the significant time discrepancy makes me think it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in checking out another tool, I am the author of a new query language and command-line tool for JSON queries and transformation, called Unquery:

https://github.com/xcite-db/Unquery

Using Unquery, this is really stright-forward:

```
{
   "stats:**": {
     "$path": {
        "$(.)" : "$count"
     }
   }
}
```

The result of the above query would be:

```
{
    "stats": {
        "content.user.details.age": {
            "21": 1,
            "30": 1,
            "60": 1
        },
        "content.user.items[0].details.heavy": {
            "false": 2,
            "true": 1
        },
        "content.user.items[0].name": {
            "hammer": 1,
            "shovel": 2
        },
        "content.user.items[1].name": {
            "hammer": 2,
            "shovel": 1
        },
        "content.user.name": {
            "Alice": 1,
            "Bill": 2
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get `user.name` instead of `content.user.name` etc., simply replace `$path` by `$substr($path,8)` (assuming the top field is always "content.", which is 8 characters).